# How to set UTF-8 atom in Phoenix.HTML.Form.select options?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to render `<select>` options with Phoenix.HTML.Form module.

```
select(form, :role, ["Admin": "admin", "User": "user"])
#=> <select id="user_role" name="user[role]">
    <option value="admin">Admin</option>
    <option value="user">User</option>
    </select>
```

Above is OK, but with below I get an error.

```
select(form, :role, ["管理者": "admin", "ユーザ": "user"])
** (ArgumentError) argument error
             :erlang.binary_to_atom("管理者", :utf8)
```

According to the document, the third argument of `Phoenix.HTML.Form.select` is a keyword list.
https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#select/4

How do I set an atom in a keyword list which contains non-ASCII character(s)? Otherwise do I have to wait for UTF-8 atom that is going to be implemented in near future?

Comment: Let me know if the question I marked this as duplicate of doesn't solve your problem!

Comment: Thank you @Dogbert! When I try with two UTF-8 Strings in a tuple, I don't get an error.